# MongoDB query to group and count records greater than and smaller than a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please help in correcting this query to group and count **Continente** based on **PIB** value greater than and smaller than 1.3?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      "item":1,
      "PIB":1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields:{
      moreThan1.3:{
        $cond:[
          {
            $gt:[
              "$PIB",
              1.3
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      },
      lessThan1.3:{
        $cond:[
          {
            $lte:[
              "$PIB",
              1.3
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      "_id":"$Continente",
      "countSmaller":{
        $sum:"$lessThan1.3"
      },
      "countBigger":{
        $sum:"$moreThan1.3"
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

This is the database in Robo 3T/MongoDB :
[image: Database in MongoDB]

This error is appearing:

> Error: Line 10: Unexpected number

Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice if you can edit this question to give sample docs in text format rather than an image !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$continente",
      /** counting docs based on condition, for an on-going doc if condition is met pass in 1 or 0 */
      countSmaller: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $lte: ["$PIB", 1.3] }, 1, 0] } },
      countBigger: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $gt: ["$PIB", 1.3] }, 1, 0] } }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Toj0cmcnBLS)

Comment: Thank you. However, an error appears. Could you please tell me if anything needs to be corrected in the query?

Comment: @Eshra : Which query did you try ? I don't think this query would throw that error !!

Comment: This query returns "Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms". Anyways to actually return the values please?

Comment: @Eshra : Replace `db.collection.aggregate` with `db.getCollection('01MBIG - Actividad 1').aggregate` !!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally used this query: db.getCollection('01MBIG - Actividad 1').countDocuments( { PIB: { $gt: ('1.4') } }, { limit: 100 } )

Comment: @Eshra : This does get you docs only with `>1.4` & that too max of 100 !! Does your question got changed entirely ?

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the query, you were close, I used `$addFields` to store the field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      "item":1,
      "PIB":1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields:{
      moreThan10:{
        $cond:[
          {
            $gt:[
              "$PIB",
              10
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      },
      lessThan10:{
        $cond:[
          {
            $lte:[
              "$PIB",
              10
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      "_id":"$Continente",
      "countSmaller":{
        $sum:"$lessThan10"
      },
      "countBigger":{
        $sum:"$moreThan10"
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Hope this will help :)

**Update**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      "item":1,
      "PIB":1
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields:{
      "moreThan1.3":{
        $cond:[
          {
            $gt:[
              "$PIB",
              1.3
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      },
      "lessThan1.3":{
        $cond:[
          {
            $lte:[
              "$PIB",
              1.3
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      "_id":"$Continente",
      "countSmaller":{
        $sum:"$lessThan1.3"
      },
      "countBigger":{
        $sum:"$moreThan1.3"
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you. I included your feedback in the original post. However, an error is appearing. Could you please say if anything needs to be corrected in the query?

Comment: The updated query says "Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms"

Comment: The quotes were missing in your query, I have updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: Thank you. You helped a lot. Finally used this query: db.getCollection('01MBIG - Actividad 1').countDocuments( { PIB: { $gt: ('1.4') } }, { limit: 100 } )